# automate and attach a VIM script to an event

Tags: vim

I have a small vim function say myFunc() defined in my .vimrc and have this function mapped to to keyword in normal mode say cl and i am successfully able to call this function whenever i type cl in normal mode, myFunc() is invoked.

Now I want to go one step further, I want this function myFunc automatically called whenever press i to go from normal mode to insert mode in vim

Please suggest how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use an auto command on InsertEnter.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * call MyFunc()
```

Noter user defined functions must start with a capital letter.

Take a look at `:help autocmd` and `:help InsertEnter`.

Comment: Let me quickly try this and update if it works or not. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Works perfectly and this is what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Pardon me, as i don't have reputation for an upvote